# Plot with two phases: user input phase and animated plot phase

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, animation, gui-construction, user-interface

Here I present what I created:

```
DynamicModule[
 {sliderA = 1, sliderB = 1, animateTime = 2 Pi, player = 1, 
  turnMaxTime = 5, turnTime = 5},
 Column@{
   (* timer with remining turn time 
   NOTE: not sure if this is best implementation for such a task *)
   Row@{
     "Remaining time: ",
     Animator[Dynamic@turnTime, {turnMaxTime, 0, 1}, 
      AppearanceElements -> "ProgressSlider", 
      AnimationRunning -> 
       Dynamic@Which[animateTime < 2 Pi, False, animateTime == 2 Pi, True], 
      ImageSize -> 500],
     " " , 
     Dynamic@Which[animateTime < 2 Pi, False, animateTime == 2 Pi, 
       True], " ",
     Dynamic[turnTime]
     },
   (* sliders providing user input *)
   Row@{
     "sliderA ", 
     Slider[Dynamic@sliderA, {-1, 1}, Appearance -> "Labeled"],
     "sliderB ", 
     Slider[Dynamic@sliderB, {-1, 1}, Appearance -> "Labeled"]},
   (* second timer which is supposed to start when the first reaches 0,
   when this one reaches max value it should start again the first timer *)
   Row@{
     "Animate timer: ",
     Animator[Dynamic@animateTime, {0, 2 Pi, Pi/10}, 3, 
      AppearanceElements -> "ProgressSlider", 
      AnimationRunning -> 
       Dynamic@Which[turnTime < 5, False, turnTime == 5, True], 
      ImageSize -> 500],
     " " , Dynamic@Which[turnTime < 5, False, turnTime == 5, True], 
     " ",
     Dynamic[animateTime]},
   Dynamic[
    Plot[sliderA Sin[sliderB x], {x, 0, animateTime + .1}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-1.1, 1.1}}, ImageSize -> 600, 
     AspectRatio -> 1/3]]
   }
 ]
```

What I was trying to achive, was some kind of turn-based user input, first user has a finite time to set `sliderA` and `sliderB` values, when the time reaches zero it should trigger an animation of plot being drawn with parameters set before (`sliderA`, `sliderB`). If you run this code you will see that I failed hard :D 
I find it rather complicated, probably because I'm new to Mathematica, however this one seems be working in some way. For example I dont know why the first `Animator@turnTime` seems to be running even when the statement of its `AnimationRunning` option is false (`turnTime` value is changing even if the slider is not moving). Can you tell me how can I implement such behaviour in Mathematica? I'll be gratefull for any kind of help - articles, sites, tutorials (I may add I've read these about Dynamic and Manipulate provided by Wolfram as well as function documentation) or code samples. Kind regards, M.